# finding difference between list elements in Tcl

Tags: tcl, vmd

I am a beginner in using Tcl. I am using it as VMD (molecular visualization) software uses it as a scripting language.
I have a list of co-ordinates of atom positions for a protein like: `{{1 2 3} {7 9 13}, ...}` I have a separate list of the same length with different positions say: `{{3 5 2} {7 3 8}, ...}`.
VMD has an inbuilt `vecsub` function which can subtract `{1 2 3}` and `{3 5 2}` to give `{-2 -3 1}`. I have written a `foreach` loop to iterate on the entire list and calculate `vecsub`.
My code is as follows:\

```
set sel1 [atomselect 0 "protein"] # selecting protein1
set sel2 [atomselect 1 "protein"] # selecting protein2
# create a list of same length as protein to store values
# $sel1 get index returns length of protein
foreach i [$sel1 get index] {
    lappend x 0 
}
# veclength2 returns square of vector length
# $sel1 get {x y z} returns a position list as described earlier
foreach i [$sel1 get index] {
    lset x $i [expr [veclength2 [vecsub [lindex [$sel1 get {x y z}] $i] [lindex [$sel2 get {x y z}] $i]]]]
}
```

Is there another way to do this in Tcl? Similar to python array subtraction perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this, but it's just a guess

```
set x [lmap p1 [$sel1 get {x y z}] p2 [$sel2 get {x y z}] {
    expr [veclength2 [vecsub $p1 $p2]]
}]
```

With this, there's no need to pre-declare `$x`

Comment: I will try this and report on it.

Comment: You _probably_ don't need the `expr` in there.

Comment: Depends on what vecsub and veclength2 return. @roni can you let us know?

Comment: @glennjackman vecsub returns the vector subtraction e.g. `vecsub {2 3 5} {3 7 1}` returns `{-1 -4 4}`. veclength2 returns the value `1 + 16 + 16` i.e. `33` in this example